# Why does setting -DVCPKG_TOOLCHAIN_FILE enable me to find packages while set(VCPKG_TOOLCHAIN_FILE ...) does not?

Tags: cmake, vcpkg

Why is it that when I set the vcpkg toolchain path from the cmake configure command

```
cmake -DVCPKG_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=D:/vcpkg/script/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake ..
```

I can use `find_package`, for instance:

```
find_package(LibXml2 REQUIRED)
```

whereas if I want to set a sensible default for the vcpkg toolchain file using a cmake cached variable

```
set(VCPKG_TOOLCHAIN_FILE D:/vcpkg/script/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake CACHE FILEPATH "vcpkg toolchain path")
```

then the same `find_package` command fails with:

```
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.18/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:165 (message):
  Could NOT find LibXml2 (missing: LIBXML2_INCLUDE_DIR)
```

what am I missing here?

Comment: You set `VCPKG_TOOLCHAIN_FILE` **before** the `project()` call, don't you?

Comment: Nope, this was one of my problems. The other was that I need to set CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE == VCPKG_TOOLCHAIN_FILE before the call to project()